# .NET Core 3.1 - Encryption : use a dynamically-generated, random IV

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, encryption, sonarlint

Sonarlint is warning me a bout a critical security risk on my encrypt routines

- I don't understand why it triggers the first **aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);** but not the second
- Sonar gives me an example on how to fix it, **but if the IV is generated randomly, how do I get it back in the decrypt part** ?
- and why is the sonar **example called Encrypt() and not generateRandomIV()** ?

I found these on SO I believe

Can someone help me out?

```
public static string EncryptString(string plainText, string key)
{
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    byte[] array;

    using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
    {
        aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
        aes.IV = iv;

        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream((Stream)memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter((Stream)cryptoStream))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(plainText);
                }

                array = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    return Convert.ToBase64String(array);
}

public static string DecryptString(string cipherText, string key)
{
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

    using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
    {
        aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
        aes.IV = iv;
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        {
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream((Stream)memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader((Stream)cryptoStream))
                {
                    return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

sonar example:

```
public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] key, byte[] data, MemoryStream target)
{
    using var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
    var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(key, aes.IV); // aes.IV is automatically generated to random secure value

    using var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(target, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    cryptoStream.Write(data);

    return aes.IV;
}
```

Comment: The IV must be unpredictable, but need not be kept secret. It is usually sent alongside the ciphertext (you can simply prepend it, for instance).

Comment: I dont get it, how would it be kept secret if I contcat it to the encrypted text ?

Comment: As Peter said, the IV is **not** secret. It is fine for the IV to be public. The rule is that you must never use the same IV more than once.

Comment: and how would I decrypt it if it is encrypted with the text ?

Comment: No, you don't *encrypt* it with the text. You transmit it, *unaltered*, alongside the encrypted data (in most normal situations)

Comment: Again, you do **not** encrypt the IV. It's common to send the **unencrypted** IV alongside the ciphertext. For example, you send the **unencrypted** IV first, and then you append the **encrypted** ciphertext